# Extended Schengen holiday with non-EU spouse of EU citizen not resident in EU

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, family, eu-citizens

I'm an Australian and Italian (EU) citizen and my wife is a citizen of the Philippines.
We are living together in Australia.

We'd like to have an extended holiday (lets say 6 months) exploring the countries that make up the Schengen Area.
We have no itinerary in mind, we'd just like to arrive and roam around as tourists.

Even though my wife has the right to enter the Schengen Zone with me (given we present proof of marriage at the border) - I understand that airlines won't let her fly there without a pre-arranged visa? Is that correct?

I assume she'll have to apply for a visa from one of the Schengen member states?
We have no itinerary and no intention of becoming residents of a Schengen member state, so I'm more than a little confused about how to proceed.

What visa will she need? Will it be okay to overstay that visa as long as she's with me?

Which member state should she apply for a visa from? As we have no itinerary, I guess the first state we enter?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you intend to visit Italy? https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

Comment: We intend to visit Italy at some point in our travels.

Comment: I’ve been searching for the answer(s) to your question without being able to conclude on the correct approach. What is clear is that, although your wife does derive a right to enter the Schengen zone from you, in practice she will not be allowed to board a flight without a visa. Part111 of https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page81 covers Family Members but is silent on how long she may stay overall. I recommend you contact the Italian Embassy in Australia for advice on how to proceed, ideally with an outline itinerary.